# "No spark of constellation, No Vela no Orion"

Tags: meaning, lyrics

Can anyone tell me the meaning of these two lines in the lyrics?

> I look up to the heavens
>   But night has clouded over
>   **No spark of constellation**
>   **No Vela no Orion**

Comment: When it is cloudy at night, you cannot see the stars.  A *constellation* is a grouping of stars.  *Vela* and *Orion* are particular constellations.

Comment: Always, always provide **attribution** for literary works.

Answer (score 3):

A [constellation](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/constellation) is a pattern of stars in the sky.  "No spark of constellation" means no stars can be seen.  [Vela](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vela_%28constellation%29) and [Orion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orion_%28constellation%29) are names of constellations, so Enya is emphasizing that the sky is pitch black.  It may be important that Orion is visible in the northern hemisphere and Vela in the southern hemisphere, so the *whole* sky is empty.

As FumbleFingers pointed out, "spark" here is a bright point of light, like a star.  And it might also be important that Orion is a hunter and Vela is the sails of a ship.

Further edit: After reflecting on FumbleFingers comment about Enya being Irish, I looked at the lyrics, and a few sites have it as *Vega* not *Vela* (it sounds like Vela to me; I haven't heard Vega pronounced with a long E).  This would make some sense, since [Vega](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vega) is a very bright star in the constellation of Lyra (the Lyre) and Orion is also a very bright constellation.  The Wikipedia article verifies that Vega is also a very important star culturally.

Comment: @jackgill Link adding jinx!

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the only non-literal element in OP's example is the 'poetic' use of the word **spark** to mean something along the lines of *visible point-source of light against a dark background*. The rest is quite straightforward, except that whereas *Orion* is visible throughout the world, *Vela* is only visible in the Southern Hemisphere (and might thus not be known to many of us).

Comment: ...apropos which, Enya herself is Irish, so I can't imagine why she'd name *Vela*. It's not as if *Orion* is the only constellation known across the whole world. Maybe she just liked the sound.

Answer (score 1):

> **constellation** |ˈkɑnstəˈleɪʃən| *noun* a
> group of stars forming a recognizable
> pattern that is traditionally named
> after its apparent form or identified
> with a mythological figure. Modern
> astronomers divide the sky into
> eighty-eight constellations with
> defined boundaries.
>
> **Orion** |əˈraɪən| |oʊˈraɪən|
> **2** *Astronomy* a conspicuous constellation (the Hunter), said to represent a hunter holding a club and shield. It lies on the celestial equator and contains many bright stars, including Rigel, Betelgeuse, and a line of three that form Orion's belt.
>
> **Vela** |ˈvēlə; ˈvā-| |ˈviːlə| |ˈvilə|
> *Astronomy* a southern constellation
> (the Sails), lying partly in the Milky
> Way between Carina and Pyxis and
> originally considered part of Argo.

<sup>*New Oxford American*</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Vela is one of the main constellations in the southern hemisphere that ships used to use for navigation (prior to GPS), and Orion is the Northern equivalent.

She is basically saying that she is on a ship, she looks up to the 'heavens' the sky for some kind of guidance as to where she is, but the weather is cloudy so she can't see either constellation and therefore has no idea where she could be (without gps if you're in the middle of the ocean at night usually the only other form of guidance is the stars or if you're lucky enough to see land and can figure out what land you're near, you can also use maps and compass but if you've drifted slightly off course at any point you could be anywhere and the easiest way to check you're on course is to use the stars of you can see them).